# Tensorlayer fails with Tensorflow 1.10.0rc0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorlayer

I just updated Tensorflow from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0 and Tensorlayer refuse to launch:

```
python
import tensorlayer as tl

../../../virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorlayer/__init__.py:22: in <module>
    "TensorLayer does not support Tensorflow version older than 1.6.0.\n"
E   RuntimeError: TensorLayer does not support Tensorflow version older than 1.6.0.
E   Please update Tensorflow with:
E    - `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`
E    - `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`
```

Any idea how to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we are fixing this right now, please wait until tonight that the new version 1.9.1 will be release to address this issue ;)

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

By downgrading to Tensorflow 1.9.0, until the maintainers of Tensorlayer fix the bug described below.

The stringly-typed [version check in Tensorlayer](https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/23066013876f8ca3bd507daaec52b73e51f1d1bb/tensorlayer/__init__.py#L20-L26) is broken when the TF version is `"1.10.0"`:

```
>>> "1.9.0" < "1.6.0"
False
>>> "1.10.0" < "1.6.0"
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll wait for the new version.